# Rsync equiv of "do not terminate"

Tags: rsync

Is there anyway to not terminate, but instead when this type of error is encountered?

```
sent 605.85M bytes  received 19.89G bytes  483.43K bytes/sec
total size is 248.71G  speedup is 12.13
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at /home/lapo/package/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3.0.9/main.c(1518) [generator=3.0.9]
```

Comment: rsync is not terminating here -- it's just informing you about previously encountered errors, which it just marked and continued (like you want).